# How to combine element ID with data-id in JQuery Function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a press ENTER function but it does not work when I combine the element id with its row id or data id. Here is code:

HTML

```
<td class="single-line" id="celledit1{{$d->id}}" contenteditable="true" data-id="{{$d->id}}">{{ $d->male }}</td>
                            <td class="single-line" id="celledit2{{$d->id}}" contenteditable="true" data-id="{{$d->id}}">{{ $d->female }}</td>
```

Script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#celledit1" + $(this).data('id')).keyup(function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                  // apply function
                  id = $(this).data('id');
                  male = 1;
                  female = 1;
                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: './editItem_enroll_male',
                      data: {
                          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                          'id': id,
                          'male': male,
                          'female': female
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                        if ((data.msg)) 
                      {
                        toastr.warning('Record not found! Record might has been deleted earlier or has been altered.', 'Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                         $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                      }else{
                        toastr.success('Successfully updated this record!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                      }
                      },
                  });
              }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Can somebody from experts here solve my problem. I admit I am still in the learning process using JS scripts, so please undertand me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it the way you tried because `this` won't be an element. You could use attribute selector `[data-id]` instead. Or add common class `cell-edit` and use it as a selector if attribute selector is too broad.

And you need to use `var`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-id]').keyup(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
              // apply function
              var id = $(this).data('id');
              var male = 1;
              var female = 1;
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: './editItem_enroll_male',
                  data: {
                      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                      'id': id,
                      'male': male,
                      'female': female
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if ((data.msg)) 
                  {
                    toastr.warning('Record not found! Record might has been deleted earlier or has been altered.', 'Oops Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                     $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                  }else{
                    toastr.success('Successfully updated this record!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                  }
                  },
              });
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is great!!! Now it's working. Thank you @Yury Tarabanko. I'll follow your advice. Sorry I can't vote this as the answer, im still not allowed to. :(

Comment: @ResnefImmatong Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
  $("#celledit1" + $('[data-id="id"]')).keyup(function (e) {
   });
```

where `data-id="your-id"`.